# Is there a standard terminology for $|f^{-1}(y)|=1$ for almost every $y$?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, terminology, sobolev-spaces, geometric-measure-theory

Let $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ be a nice open, connected, bounded subset (say with Lipschitz boundary) and let $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a Lipschitz map.

Is there a standard terminology for the following property?

$|f^{-1}(y)| \le 1$ for almost every $y \in \mathbb R^n$, where $|f^{-1}(y)|=1$ refers to the cardinality of the preimage.

I guess that reasonable suggestions could be "injective a.e. in the image" or "almost injective" or something like that. However, I wonder whether there is an accepted terminology I could use, and I don't want to "overload" or get into conflict with other terminologies. (I can guess that "almost injective" could be referring to a map which is injective after you exclude a set of measure zero from your domain).

(The mathematical context is the Area/Coarea formula.)

Comment: I don't know if there is a name for this, but it's closely related to Banach's condition $(T_1)$ (for almost all $y$ the set $f^{-1}(y)$ is finite) and Banach's condition $(T_2)$ (for almost all $y$ the set $f^{-1}(y)$ is finite or countably infinite) for real-valued functions of one real variable (see [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Banach%27s+condition+T2%22) and Section IX.6 on pp. 277-282 of [**Theory of the Integral**](https://archive.org/details/theoryoftheinteg032192mbp/page/n287/mode/2up) by Stanisław Saks), so maybe searches in this literature might lead to something.

Comment: If you find yourself having to make up a name, maybe you could use $(T_0),$ explaining that the name was inspired by the classical real variable $(T_1)$ and $(T_2)$ Banach conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least in the context of elasticity theory, this is known as "injectivity almost everywhere", see, e.g., Ciarlet's "Mathematical Elasticity vol. 1", Problem 5.7 (following the work of Ball) and Section 7.9 (following Ciarlet-Nečas).

Comment: To be more accurate, the property is, of course, that the cardinality of f^{-1}(y) is *at most* one for almost every y.

Comment: @Asaf Shachar: Unless the phrase needs to be used almost everywhere in a manuscript, this is much better than something like $(T_0),$ because C M's phrase/symbolism is strongly suggestive of what the property is.